# Django и MS SQL Server

Tags: python, django, sql-server

Я совсем недавно начал изучать Django и столкнулся с проблемой: нужно получать данные из SQL Server в мое Django приложение. Все настройки в Settings я выполнил, но что делать дальше? Как обратиться к таблице, хранящейся на сервере? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть библиотека `pyodbc`, через неё можете попробовать. Подключаетесь к серверу, например так:

```
pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=server, database=database, 
               Trusted_Connection=True)
```

или с указанием реквизитов:

```
pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server=server, database=database,
               uid=user, pwd=password)
```

И затем можете выполнять какие-нибудь запросы:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT name, age FROM people')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row.name, row.age)

connection.close()
```

Примечание: При закрытии соединения курсор закрывается автоматически.